# What is the default sort order of a Content Query Web Part in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part, sorting

If no sort order is specified in a CQWP, how does SharePoint determine the order to place the items?  Is there a default field that it uses to sort if no sorting is specified in the CQWP options?

Answer (score 0):

The default sort option at CQWP is `descending via created column` that means the newest item first.

[image]

If you set the `sort item by` to `None` at CQWP, it will sort `ascending via created column` that means the older items first.

**To make sure that,** I tried to add a CQWP at the same "all items" page for a list , without changing anything at `presentations` section , so it will sort **by default** as `descending via created column` as shown below

[image]

If you set `sort item by` to `None` at CQWP it will be the same as default view that sort `ascending via created column`

[image]